# For/in function prints all variables (on same line) instead of just one in python. Solution?

Tags: python

```py
x = [876, 1000, 1570, 1988, 2500]

for size in x:
    print(f"The tax for engine size is €{x}cc {calc_size(size)}")
```

the output is: The tax for engine size is €[876, 1000, 1570, 1988, 2500]cc 250
(and 4 more lines for each variable)

I want the output to be: The tax for engine size is €876cc 250

Any help appreciated

Comment: f"The tax for engine size is €{size}cc {calc_size(size)}"

Comment: Well, you told it to put `x` into the string, each time through the loop, and `x` is equal to the entire list. Each time through the loop, you let `size` be one of the elements of the list. You want that element of the list to appear at that point in the string. So....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you misplaced a variable. Also, I'd recommend renaming `calc_size` to `calc_tax` in your code, if that makes sense.

```
x = [876, 1000, 1570, 1988, 2500]

for size in x:
    print(f"The tax for engine size €{size}cc is {calc_tax(size)}")
```

**Output**

```
The tax for engine size €876cc is ...
The tax for engine size €1000cc is ...
The tax for engine size €1570cc is ...
The tax for engine size €1988cc is ...
The tax for engine size €2500cc is ...
```